# Amplifying pulse from 4 V to 24 V

Tags: amplifier, pulse, square

I currently have a problem where I want to amplify a 4V square pulse signal to a 24V square pulse signal, for a Q-switch input.

I tried using op-amps (LM358N) in a non-inverting amplifier configuration but they didn’t work. I read online that the op-amps have too small of a bandwidth for small rise time (2-3ns).

The current 4V square pulse is generated by the Stanford Standard pulse generator (DG535). Manual link: https://www.thinksrs.com/downloads/pdfs/manuals/DG535m.pdf

I have also attached a drawing of the pulse. The flash lamp signal is already present, I included the pulse drawing to show why I needed the DG535 (to give the 582 microsecond delay). The Q-switch signal is what I need right now.

I have a power supply that can go from 0V to 25V. I don’t have a circuit schematic of what the 24V square signal will drive, but the laser manual tells me I need a 24V signal.

Are there any other possible ways for me to amplify the signal? Please recommend a suitable part.

[image: diagram of required pulse]

Comment: Um, 24V is definitely not TTL (that's short for "transistor-to-transistor logic", and defines the voltage ranges, at least rudimentarily). So, what do you mean when you say "4V TTL" and "24V TTL", actually? And what did you try with  opamps? And you read something online. Where did you read it? TTL is not about speed, so "TTL" doesn't tell us anything about required bandwidth. And: we do not do part recommendations, that's expicitly off-topic here. Please describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve, and what you've tried (and that means: show us the schematic of what you've built).

Comment: Do you mean you want to amplifier a 4V peak-to-peak square wave signal to a 24V peak-to-peak square wave signal? Knowing characteristics of the signal, such as frequency, would also help.

Comment: 0 to 24 to 0 in what slew rate and current output depends on load impedance and source Rs of switch. Consider High side IC switches with TTL enable.

Comment: How about a low side switch?

Comment: 3ns @ 24V driving any parasitic load C pF draws a lot of current so the driver and stray C must be minimized. If dt=2ns and dV=24V,  and C= 10 pF , Ic=CdV/dt= 1e-11 * 24 / 2e-9= 48e-2 ~ 0.5A this means source impedance needs to be ~1% of load =24/0.5A *1%= .5 ohm which needs a power FET half bridge

Comment: It seems like the best bet would be to set the DC supply to 24V, and use a fast switch to pulse it. Can you provide a make and model and link for the "laser"? Maybe we can glean more information about it than you realize by perusing documentation.

Comment: _"the laser manual tells me I need a 24V signal"_ - it should tell you more than that. Please provide a link to the manual or photograph the page with this information on it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact nature of the load it is difficult to give precise advice, however if the load is primarily resistive or capacitive with <1nF capacitance, a gate driver chip can be a good starting point. For example, the IZYZ [IDX802](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/IXD_602.pdf/$file/IXD_602.pdf) has tr/tf of 6.5/7ns typical with a 1nF load and can handle supply voltage up to 35V It would be okay driving a pulsed 50\$\Omega\$ load.

I am a bit suspicious that you may not actually need a driver like this. My understanding is that Q-switches require high voltage and/or RF for Pockels cells etc. so this may simply be the control input for a Q-switch driver (in which case it might be able to accept TTL levels directly). Please provide data as Bruce suggests if you want us to look at it and suggest something that might meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I looked at the MAX1502x and I believe that the max voltage output is only 11V.

Comment: 18V (22V abs max) for the DRV voltage.  Maybe there is a better gate driver chip.

Comment: Edited with a better chip now that I have a desktop PC at hand.

Comment: There should be a standard synchronizer that comes with the laser but unfortunately, we did not get the synchronizer so I had to make the signals myself. In the manual, only the pulse shape was given. I can try sharing the pdf file.